# Create and run stored procedure using Grails database migration plugin

Tags: mysql, grails, database-migration

I'm trying to do a slightly awkward database migration, and I'm using a stored procedure to update some rows in one of my application's tables. The stored procedure runs ok if I execute it using the mysql command line tool, or in Sequel Pro, however it doesn't run if I try to run it using the database migration plugin.

It looks like liquibase supports stored procedures, but the database migration plugin seems to blow up. Does anyone know if this should work?

The error (and the complete stored procedure) are shown below:

```
    2014-03-08 09:05:21,693 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  liquibase  - ChangeSet changelog_fb_contactForm_2_add_new_enquiry_roles.groovy::1393960870500-1::rcgeorge23 ran successfully in 6671ms
    | Error 2014-03-08 09:05:21,704 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR liquibase  - Change Set changelog_fb_contactForm_3_add_enquiry_flexible_model_definition_to_existing_organisations.groovy::1393960870500-1::rcgeorge23
     failed.  Error: Error executing SQL DELIMITER // 
                            CREATE PROCEDURE ABC() 
                            BEGIN 
                                    REPEAT 
                                            set @organisationConfigurationId = (select id from organisation_configuration oc where oc.enquiry_flexible_model_definition_id is null limit 1); 
                                            insert into flexible_model_definition (`version`, `name`) values ('0', 'enquiry.flexible.model'); 
                                            set @newlyInsertedEnquiryFlexibleModelDefinitionId = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
                                            update organisation_configuration oc set oc.enquiry_flexible_model_definition_id = @newlyInsertedEnquiryFlexibleModelDefinitionId where oc.id = @organisationConfigurationId
    ; 
                                    UNTIL 0 = (select count(*) from organisation_configuration oc where oc.enquiry_flexible_model_definition_id is null) 
                            END REPEAT; 
                            END //: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // 
                            CREATE PROCEDURE ABC() 
                            BEGIN 
                                    REPEAT 
                                            set @organis' at line 1
    Message: Error executing SQL DELIMITER // 
                            CREATE PROCEDURE ABC() 
                            BEGIN 
                                    REPEAT 
                                            set @organisationConfigurationId = (select id from organisation_configuration oc where oc.enquiry_flexible_model_definition_id is null limit 1); 
                                            insert into flexible_model_definition (`version`, `name`) values ('0', 'enquiry.flexible.model'); 
                                            set @newlyInsertedEnquiryFlexibleModelDefinitionId = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
                                            update organisation_configuration oc set oc.enquiry_flexible_model_definition_id = @newlyInsertedEnquiryFlexibleModelDefinitionId where oc.id = @organisationConfigurationId
    ; 
                                    UNTIL 0 = (select count(*) from organisation_configuration oc where oc.enquiry_flexible_model_definition_id is null) 
                            END REPEAT; 
                            END //: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // 
                            CREATE PROCEDURE ABC() 
                            BEGIN 
                                    REPEAT 
                                            set @organis' at line 1
        Line | Method
    ->>   62 | execute                        in liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |    104 | execute                        in     ''
    |   1091 | execute . . . . . . . . . . .  in liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase
    |   1075 | executeStatements              in     ''
    |    317 | execute . . . . . . . . . . .  in liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet
    |     27 | visit                          in liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor
    |     58 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `splitStatements` when defining stored procedures, e.g.:

`sqlFile path:'my_stored_procedure.sql', splitStatements: false`

Otherwise the database migration plugin will try to be smart and split your statements which will blow up your definition.

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't use the stored procedure in the end, but I'll give this a try if I need to in future.

Answer (score -1):

**runOnChange='true'** configuration forces the plugin to check if the change set was changed instead of just checking if it was run once before so it can be skipped.

By default the sql statement in the file is split on ;’s to avoid this **splitStatements = 'false'** configuration is used to makes sure the complete create procedure script is read as one instead of splitting it on ;’s for each individual sql statement inside.

**Example:**

```
changeSet(author: "Rahul", id: "1435600003872-128", runOnChange: "true") {
    sql("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS BestCustomers;")
    sqlFile(path: "../sql/BestCustomers.sql", splitStatements: false)
}
```

Code for BestCustomers.sql :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `BestCustomers`(
     //Input params here
   )
BEGIN
    //Sql scripts here ;
END
```

A step by step guide can be found [here](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/migrating-stored-procedures-with-grails-database-migration-plugin/).

Praise goes to Rahul Babu.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just reviewed the answer on review pipes